# Time based triggers in google apps script - executions and limitations

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

1. If I have hundreds of triggers set to work on a specific day of the week within the same hour time frame (lets say Monday between 8 am to 9 am) - will they be executed in the way that will burden the least on the server?

If not - according to which consideration the execution time will be determine?

2. Is there a limtation of **amount** of triggers in an hour/day? What is it? (in [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) I found only a Triggers total **runtime**).

Thanks!

Comment: The execution time for each trigger will depend on the code you have in each trigger function. Each trigger is treated separately. The time in which the trigger is executed doesn't affect this, at least from your side, and from the server side you can't know when the server is less crowded but the difference would be minimal. You can have up to [20 triggers per user per script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). Is this the information you need?

Comment: This is helpful. What I want to know is if there is a way to know when within the 1 hour time frame is a trigger likely to get executed. I am assuming it is not random and what to understand what affects it. I am taking about multiple triggers to the same function, each one from a separate spreadsheet

Comment: Also- in "20 triggerst / user / script" is "script" refers to the source of the trigger (project that is associated with the trigger) or its' target (library with the actual function is placed)? [I can open another question, but this seem relevant to this one]

Comment: They will all for sure be executed, if what you mean is if they will have a specific order, they won't. If you only [set the hour](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) they will be triggered at a random minute within the next hour (from 8:00 to 9:00 in your example). If you also set the minute with [nearMinute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) function, they'll try to be executed at that minute with +-15 minutes of precision error, which is the maximum precision you can have.

Comment: "Script" refers to the actual script containing the code function your're targeting.

Comment: Thank you Andres. So in my example- the library, right? Is it 20 triggers for a specific function in the library or the code file in general?

Comment: In Apps Script editor (script) go to the menu and click "Edit" -> "current project's triggers" , that way you can see where the triggers are created. In your case the 20 triggers are for the script (project that is associated with the trigger) because the code you use from a library it's applied the same as if you would have it in the source script directly without library intervention.

Comment: Let me know if it help you to post an answer with a summary of all the comments.

Comment: Our discussion drifted away a bit from the origina lquestion, but the information in indeed useful to the overall understanding of the topic